# Excel 2010 - checking a list of values in a cell against a table column and outputting those that don't match

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column that includes lists of values - I want to look up each value in each cell in that column against a column in another table and identify which ones are not in that table

So my table is as follows (let's say in Column A);

Value A

Value B

Value C

Value D

The column of data I want to check against the above is as follows (Let's say Column D);

Value D

Value B,Value D

Value A

Value D,Value E,Value A

Value C

Value F

Value G,Value E,Value A

so that my output would be as follows (column E);

""

""

""

Value E

""

Value F

Value G, Value E

is there an array formula using a combination of formulas such as 'Search' or 'Find' that will allow me to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substitute function, but you can only nest it a limited number of times.  You would also need to parse for extra commas if you intend to do it that way.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D1, A$1, ""), A$2, ""), A$3, ""), A$4, ""), ",,", ",")
```

This got me the proper values, but it is hard-coded to your four values in column A.  You can then use *LEFT()* and *RIGHT()* functions to check if the first and last characters are a comma and use those results to parse your result.

If you remove the commas and just use spaces, you won't have to parse it, and you could replace the double coma substitute check with a double space check.

Comment: Thank you

How many nested ifs can I have? I have 64 in my list

Comment: I think you can nest `SUBSTITUTE` and `IF` 7 times.  Take a look at this link for some alternatives to nesting `IF`.  Alternatively, you could parse a few values out per column and use the new result to continue parsing past 7 values.  You could then hide the `helper` columns so that you only see the true result.